# Proving equinumerosity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I'm studying for my set theory exam on Monday and I'm having some trouble with a practice problem. Hoping you guys can help!

Let $Surj(\mathbb{N})$ be the set of surjective functions $$f : \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$ Prove that $$\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\sim Surj(\mathbb{N})$$

So I have the answer here, but if someone could help explain it I'd appreciate it: 
($\Rightarrow$) we know that since $Surj(\mathbb{N})$ is of the form $f : \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N},$ $Surj(\mathbb{N}) \preceq \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$. The problem is with ($\Leftarrow$). How can I define the powerset of the natural numbers to the $Surj(\mathbb{N})$? 
Thank you in advance for all your help!
[image]

Comment: You say "I have the answer here", but you have not shared it with us. How can we explain the answer if we don't know what it is?

Comment: @RonArthan do you think a picture would be okay? It's hard to format.￼

Comment: If a picture is the best you can do, then use a picture.

Comment: @RobArthan there we go. Sorry about that.

Comment: If I understand your argument, you rely on $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \sim 2^\mathbb{N}$ to conclude that $Surj(\mathbb{N}) \preceq \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.  Then you show an injection from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to $Surj(\mathbb{N})$.  What is still missing in your opinion?

Comment: What problems do you have with the mapping $S \mapsto f_S : \mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N}) \to \mathsf{Surj}(\Bbb{N})$ defined first pictorially and then formally by an equation in the image?